# int.TryParse returning false on the first line of data from StreamReader

Tags: c#

Long time reader, first time poster.

I'm simply reading numbers from a text file to into an integer array, one integer per line, using the `StreamReader` class. I read through the file once to get the number of lines so I can properly define the destination array. I then reset the pointer to the beginning of the text file and read again, this time using `int.TryParse` covert the strings to integers and write to the array. But the first line from the file returns 'false' from the TryParse - even though the string is merely '3. The subsequent lines return 'true' just fine. Here's the snippet ...

```
        _NumbersInMemory = new int[lineCount];

        theFileStream.DiscardBufferedData();
        theFileStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, 0);

        lineCount = 0;
        do
        {
            string theLineFromTheFle = theFileStream.ReadLine();
            int numberInMemoryTemporarily = 0;
            bool result = int.TryParse(theLineFromTheFle, out numberInMemoryTemporarily);
            if (result)
            {
                _NumbersInMemory[lineCount] = numberInMemoryTemporarily;
            }
            lineCount++;
        } while (!theFileStream.EndOfStream);

        theStream.Close();
```

Is the reset to the beginning of the file (which is only 82 lines) messing-up the input to the first iteration of TryParse, or something like that?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a space after the `3`?

Comment: "even though the string is merely '3" ... is it '3 or 3?

Comment: Why not use File.ReadAllLines instead..? Also, try trimming the string first

Comment: Also, not really related to your question, but: As I assume, your current code relies on the fact that the file has at least on line in it (do-while loop).

Comment: Just to be picky, the second parameter to Seek should be SeekOrigin.Begin, not zero.  Using meaningful constants makes your code more readable.

Comment: Thanks all ... its just plain-vanilla 3 on the first line, 65 on the second (which works fine) etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file probably has UTF8 or Unicode byte-order-marks (BOM) at the start of the file. Looking at the file in a hex-viewer can verify this.

When you first open the file, the `StreamReader` class reads these bytes to determine the proper encoding of the rest of the file. The first `ReadLine()` will not include these bytes.

By seeking to byte 0 of the underlying stream, the next `ReadLine()` will include these bytes because the `StreamReader` does not know it should skip them (it's already read and processed them).

Either read the file once by using `ReadAllLines`, or close and re-open the file to start reading again rather than seeking back to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using this code instead:

```
_NumbersInMemory =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"path")
        .Select(line => line.Trim())
        .Select(line =>
        {
            int numberInMemoryTemporarily = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(line, out numberInMemoryTemporarily))
            {
                return numberInMemoryTemporarily;
            }
            return 0;
        })
        .ToArray();
```

The `.Select(line => line.Trim())` may be enough to get rid of the problem you have.